# Unity 2D C# - no collision inside an object

Tags: c#, collision-detection, collision, unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-gui

I want to know, how to get no collision inside an object.
 I have a big circle and inside the circle is a smaller square. When the game starts, the circle is scaling down. 
And what i want, is to check the collision, if circle is touching or is inside the square.

Can you please help me ? Thank you

Comment: Do both the circle and the square have the same center? Because if so, you could use basic maths and wouldn't need any collision detection at all.

Comment: Yeah, they have same center. And other thing, that i want to mention is about changing sprite of the gameobject. The circle can be changed on the triangle or square and other geometric things

Comment: But it will be ok, if you tell me how to detect the collision of these two object ( square - circle)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no built-in way of achieving this in Unity (There is also not a built-in way of detecting whether a collider is fully inside another collider or not).

If I understood you correctly your circle is going to shrink and when it reaches this point

[image]

you want to do something *e.g. execute some code*.

The way you could make it work for a circle and a square just based on maths would be this:

If the sides of your square are of length `a` and your circle has a decreasing radius of `r`, then at the moment you see in the image above the relation between the two of them is:

```
r = a / sqrt(2)
```

So you could check `if (r <= a / Mathf.Sqrt(2))` in the `Update` function and based on that call some function. (Maybe add another boolean to ensure the function only gets called once.)

You can get your sprite widths using

```
width = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x;
```

The radius of your circle would then obviously be half the width of the circle sprite.

*You should probably also store the `SpriteRenderer` in a variable once instead of calling `GetComponent` on every frame.*

For an equilateral triangle the equation would be

```
r = a / sqrt(3)
```

where `a` is the length of the triangle's side.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. And what about that triangle ? If triangle will be there instead square ( Big circle - smaller triangle)

Comment: Well, that would depend on the specific triange shape. Is it an equilateral triangle?

Comment: Yes, that triangle

Comment: @CallMany I added that to the answer as well.

Comment: @CallMany Are you sure that you divided your circle sprite width by two to get the radius? If you don't you'll simply be calculating using the diameter instead of the radius which works as long as you multiply by `sqrt(2)` instead of divide.

Comment: Yes, that's it... Thanks